# How echo and update dynamic options in html php form

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I want to echo and update these options in php update / edit form.

Here is the html input dynamic text box options -

Here is the complete code reference.
https://phppot.com/php/php-contact-form-with-custom-fields/

```
<div class="input-row">                          
          <input style="width:49%!important; float:left;" type="text" placeholder="Option name" required class="custom-input-field" name="custom_name[]" />                           
          <input style="width:49%!important; float:right;" type="number"  placeholder="Price" min="0" step="0.01" required class="custom-input-field float-right" name="custom_value[]" />                                
 </div>
```

Code to enter in database

```
INSERT INTO custom_contact (name,email,subject,email_content,message,options) VALUES ('$name','$email','$subject','$emailContent','$message','$options')

if(!empty($_POST["custom_name"][0])) {
       // $emailContent .= "<p><u>Custom Information:</u></p>";
        foreach($_POST["custom_name"] as $k=>$v) {            

            $emailContent .=  "" . $_POST["custom_name"][$k] . "-" . $_POST["custom_value"][$k] . ",";

        }
    }
```

How to echo and edit these options and fields in php

Here is my sample edit/update code - I don't know what to put in value=""

Example -

```
<input style="width:49%!important; float:left;" type="text" placeholder="Option name" required class="custom-input-field" value="<?php echo$[0]["custom_name"];?>" name="custom_name[]" /> 

<input style="width:49%!important; float:right;" type="number" placeholder="Price" min="0" step="0.01" required class="custom-input-field float-right" value="<?php echo$["custom_value"][$k];?>" name="custom_value[]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are doing a foreach loop in the first part, you can echo HTML onto the page. Here is an simple example:

```
<?php
$arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

foreach($arr as $number){

echo "<input type='text' value='".$number."' />";

}
?>
```

Or if you prefer, you can break in and out of PHP and HTML to make it easier to type if there's a lot of html:

```
<?php
$arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

foreach($arr as $number){
?>

<input type='text' value='<?php echo $number; ?>' />

<?php
}
?>
```

Edit: so I’m not really understanding what you’re asking but let’s say you have an array with two items

```
$arr = [
     [ 
          “name”=>”first”,
          “value”=>1
     ],
     [
          “name”=>”second”,
          “value”=>2
      ]
];
```

You could loop on them and access the properties like so:

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
     echo $item[“name”];
     echo $item[“value”];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I still don't know how would i separate values in two boxes for custom_name and customer_value ? foreach($_POST["custom_name"] as $k=>$v) {          

            $emailContent .=  "" . $_POST["custom_name"][$k] . "-" . $_POST["custom_value"][$k] . ",";

Comment: output from database is like this -    green-12,blue-44,red-32, . So i need to put green in one box and 12 in second box and so on.

Comment: I’m not really following you but i edited my answer maybe that will help?